# how to enable a button when the from hour and minutes starts and disabled when the to hour and minutes ends

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

how to enable a button when the Fromhour and Fromminutes starts and disabled when the tohour and tominutes ends

I tried using if condition but failed during minutes checking

```js
else {
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
}
} else if (DateTime.Now.Hour == Model.FromTimeHour && DateTime.Now.Hour == Model.ToTimeHour) {
  if (DateTime.Now.Minute >= Model.FromTimeMinutes && DateTime.Now.Minute <= Model.ToTimeMinutes) {
    <input type="button" id="btn_save" style="width:auto" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" class="btn btn-info" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
    <input type="submit" id="btn_save1" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" style="display:none" />
  } else {
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
  }
} else if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= Model.FromTimeHour && DateTime.Now.Hour <= Model.ToTimeHour) {
  if (DateTime.Now.Minute >= Model.FromTimeMinutes && DateTime.Now.Minute <= Model.ToTimeMinutes) {
    <input type="button" id="btn_save" style="width:auto" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" class="btn btn-info" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
    <input type="submit" id="btn_save1" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" style="display:none" />
  } else if (DateTime.Now.Hour > Model.FromTimeHour && DateTime.Now.Hour == Model.ToTimeHour) {
    if (DateTime.Now.Minute <= Model.FromTimeMinutes && DateTime.Now.Minute <= Model.ToTimeMinutes) {
      <input type="button" id="btn_save" style="width:auto" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" class="btn btn-info" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
      <input type="submit" id="btn_save1" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" style="display:none" />
    } else {
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
    }
  } else {
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
  }
} else {
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
}

} else {
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
}
```

Comment: please format your code so it's readable - also, that's not javascript

Comment: Don't call anything in a form `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly simplify the code, THEN use the conditions

I did not examine the logic behind the actual existence of the buttons.

I also strongly recommend to rename the button if you ever want to submit the form using JavaScript. Never call anything in a form "submit"

```
@{
    bool isButtonEnabled = false;
    int currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    int currentMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

    // Check if current time is within the specified range
    if (currentHour > Model.FromTimeHour && currentHour < Model.ToTimeHour) {
        isButtonEnabled = true;
    } else if (currentHour == Model.FromTimeHour && currentMinute >= Model.FromTimeMinutes) {
        isButtonEnabled = currentHour != Model.ToTimeHour || currentMinute <= Model.ToTimeMinutes;
    } else if (currentHour == Model.ToTimeHour && currentMinute <= Model.ToTimeMinutes) {
        isButtonEnabled = true;
    }

    // Render the button based on isButtonEnabled
    if (isButtonEnabled) {
        <input type="button" id="btn_save" style="width:auto" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" class="btn btn-info" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
        <input type="submit" id="btn_save1" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" style="display:none" />
    } else {
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit Discount" disabled style="width:180px;" onchange="preventMultipleSave()" />
    }
}
```